# lack of equivalency of 1 norm and infinity norm on continous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Show that $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ are not equivalent on $\phi \in C([a,b])$.

The hint given is that you can find the upper bound, but you cant find the lower bound required for the norms to be equivalent basically there doesn't exist a $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \|\phi\|_{\infty} \leq \|\phi\|_1$ for all $\phi$.

However I'm questioning this since it seems trivially true to me that 
$\|\phi\|_{\infty} \leq \|\phi\|_1$
since $\|\phi\|_1 = \int_{a}^{b} |\phi(s)|ds$ and $\|\phi\|_{\infty} = \max\{\phi(x):\ x \in [a,b]\}$, so $\alpha$ is just $1$ in this case.

I've missed something small here. Anyone help me in proving this result?

Comment: Suppose $\phi(s)$ is $1$ when $0\le s\le 0.1$ and is $0$ otherwise. What is $\|\phi\|_1$ in this case? What is $\|\phi\|_\infty$?

Comment: infinity is  1 and 1 norm is .1. I see the point.

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in the question - you want to show that the two norms are *not* equivalent.

Indeed, there is no $\alpha$ so that $||\phi||_\infty\le\alpha||\phi||_1$ for all $\phi$. So yes, you're missing something. Hard to say what you're missing, exactly. You give the definitions of the two norms and then say it follows trivially that $||\phi||_\infty\le||\phi||_1$. This is not true, and it doesn't follow - to say what you're missing we need to know why you think it *does* follow...

**Edit** In fact the inequality $||\phi||_1\le(b-a)||\phi||_\infty$ *is* immediate from the definitions. Possibly you can find the error in your reasoning regarding the other inequality by considering a specific example.  Take $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and let $\phi(t)=t^n$. What are $||\phi||_\infty$ and $||\phi||_1$?

Comment: If $\phi $ takes a maximum somewhere in the interval, isn't this less than summing up that maximum plus other stuff, since all the other things are greater than or equal to 0? That is why it seems to me that the inf norm is less than the 1 norm.

Comment: Ah. If we were talking about sums that would be exactly right. But integrals are not sums. Or at least the integral of $\phi$ is not the sum of values of $\phi$; in fact $\int_0^1\phi$ is approximated by a sum that looks like $\sum\phi(t_j)(t_j-t_{j-1})$.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Really helpful.